# Removing a data point from a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to remove a datapoint from a plot [actually move it along a number line] but when I use the remove function I get "remove() takes exactly one argument (0 given)"
I do not want to use clf() to clear it all out because I don't want to redraw the frames via setup(ax) every time i move the point.

```py
x = 1.283
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
setup(ax)
movepoint = ax.plot(x, 0.02, 'rv')
plt.pause(1)

while x <= 1.3:
        movepoint.remove()
        x += 0.001
        movepoint = ax.plot(x, 0.02, 'rv')
        plt.pause(0.000001)

plt.show()
```

So what does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: "I do not want to use clf() to clear it all out because I don't want to redraw the frames"... why not?

Comment: Regarding your actual error: movepoint is a list, and the remove function requires one argument (i.e. the element to be removed from the list)

Comment: @Reblochon Masque: maybe because doing so would incur a significant performance penalty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to modify the x-value of the plotted data. This can be done by the `set_xdata()` method ([see doc](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html?highlight=line2d%20set_xdata#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_xdata)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = 1.283
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(left=1.25, right=1.35)  # optional
movepoint, = ax.plot(x, 0.02, 'rv')  # the ',' makes movepoint the Line2D instance instead of a 1-element list
# plt.pause(1)  # not sure what purpose that would serve

while x <= 1.3:
    x += 0.001
    movepoint.set_xdata([x])
    plt.pause(0.1)  # long enough to see something
```

Comment: Changing the x data doesn't work.  'list' object has no attribute 'set_xdata'

Comment: Did you run the code I gave you unmodified? As hinted to in the code comment, `movepoint, = ax.plot(...)` is very different from `movepoint = ax.plot(...)`.

Comment: missed the comma.  I'm teaching myself python si as a hijack what does the comma do?

Comment: @SaintCad `a, = stuff` is similar to `a, b, c = stuff`: it makes Python unpack the iterator on the right and assign values to each of the variables on the left. In that exact case, there is only one value to assign, but you still need to unpack, because `ax.plot()` returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to just remove the line from the actual axis?

```
x = 1.283
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
setup(ax)
ax.plot(x, 0.02, 'rv')
plt.pause(1)

while x <= 1.3:
        ax.lines.pop(0)
        x += 0.001
        ax.plot(x, 0.02, 'rv')
        plt.pause(0.000001)

plt.show()
```

Or do you want to create an animation, where the https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/animation_api.html package can help you?